# C programming - globally seen instance

Tags: c, buffer

I want to declare an instance of a structure which will be accessible in all source files. To be more precise, I have a structure which represents a ring buffer. Two parts of my program can write to the buffer, so I need somehow to share the same instance of the buffer between my source files. This was my idea but it is not working:

To declare instance of buffer as extern in buf.h file and to make function `ringBuf_get()` which would return pointer to instance of my buffer.

```
extern ringBuf buf_frames;
ringBuf *ringBuf_get(void);
```

So I would implement `ringBuf_get()` like this in `buf.c`:

```
ringBuf *ringBuf_get(void)
{
    return &buf_frames;
}
```

Then whenever I want to make some operation on buffer, I would first call `ringBuf_get` to get instance of buffer and then I would make operation. But it seems that I am doing something wrong. Feel free to comment.

```
bool ringBuf_write(ringBuf *_this, uint8_t *mac_protocol_data_unit, uint8_t length)
{
    if(_this->write->alloc == false)
    {
        _this->write->alloc = true;
        _this->write->len = length;
        memcpy(_this->write->data, mac_protocol_data_unit, length);
        if(_this->write == &_this->buf_pool[MAX_BUF_POOL_SIZE])
            _this->write = &_this->buf_pool[0];
        else
            _this->write++;
        xil_printf("\n\n Write Suceeded! \n\n");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ringBuf_full(_this))
        {
           xil_printf("\n\n BUFFER IS FULL! \n\n");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong? Do you mean you face compiling issues or malfunctiones in the executed program?

Comment: This is what I get as result of execution, for example my buffer has maximum size of 4 frames to store inside. And I am trying to write 5 times into it and it is always able to write into it, although I should be able to write just 4 times. I will post write function too.

Comment: Ok I added also write function. When I write to buffer I also set alloc to 1. So if I am writing 4 times, all allocs should be on 1, and I would not be able to write again in buffer. The code is working if I make instance of my buffer inside main and call functions on it.

Comment: Note that names starting with underscore are reserved for the implementation, so it is best to avoid using them yourself.  Hence `_this` is not advisable as a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the header to declare

```
extern ringBuf buf_frames;
```

The function is sufficient — and it is better to expose just the function and not the global variable.  Indeed, the variable should be made `static` in the file that defines it (and there must be such a file; presumably it would be `buf.c`).  Making the variable `static` means other files cannot access it by name, but they can call the function to get a pointer to the variable and then access it.

#### Auxilliary Q&A

> It seems that every time I write:
>
> ```
> ringBuf_write(ringBuf_get(), packet1, 127);
> ringBuf_write(ringBuf_get(), packet2, 64);
> ringBuf_write(ringBuf_get(), packet1, 127);
> ```
>
> I get a new instance by calling `ringBuf_get()`. So instead of movingthe  pointer and writing to another frame in the buffer, I write to the same frame. Also the buffer does not remember that I have already allocated, for example, frame 0.

Then you need to review your question and explain what is going wrong, preferably with an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.

You wrote the `ringBuf_get()` function to return a pointer to the same data structure each time.  That's probably correct, but it is not then clear what you mean by 'I get new instance by calling `ringBuf_get()`'.  You get the same instance each time.  If you've not updated that instance correctly, or you need to point to a different instance each time, you need to fix the code.

It is not clear where you check that the memory to copied to `_this->write->data` is small enough to fit.

Also, it is not clear how big the `_this->buf_pool` array is.  If it is not of size `MAX_BUF_POOL_SIZE+1`, you have a problem writing out of bounds in the code:

```
    if(_this->write == &_this->buf_pool[MAX_BUF_POOL_SIZE])
        _this->write = &_this->buf_pool[0];
    else
        _this->write++;
```

Arguably the damage is done by the `memcpy()` before that.  The code that sets `_this->alloc = true;` without allocating memory is worrying, too.  I can't say whether it is wrong or not; you've not shown enough of your code or the detailed definition of the structure.

How have you unit tested the ring-buffer code?  Where are all the diagnostic print statements that tell you that the buffers are being handled correctly?  Have you run the function in a debugger if you can't or refuse to add printing code?  What is the design of the ring buffers really?

Comment: I will try, seems reasonable. And inform you about this.

Comment: Seems that every time I write  ringBuf_write (ringBuf_get(), packet1, 127);
 ringBuf_write (ringBuf_get(), packet2, 64);
 ringBuf_write (ringBuf_get(), packet1, 127);   I get new instance by calling ringBuf_get(). So instead of moving pointer and writing to another frame in buffer, I write to same frame. Also buffer does not remember that I have already allocated for example frame 0.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us much of the code, but does this statement (or others!) break an array?

```
if(_this->write == &_this->buf_pool[MAX_BUF_POOL_SIZE])
```

Typically, when you define the `SIZE` of an array, it can then be indexed in the range `0..(SIZE-1)`. I propose this since one of your problems is being able to write a 5th buffer when there are only 4.